# Custom UITableCell accessoryView offset inner image

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I'm trying to align the right side of my custom accessory view with the default discloser indicator, but I'm not sure how my UIImageView sets my image.

```
@IBOutlet var goToMessagesCell: UITableViewCell! {
    didSet {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(
            name: .comment,
            style: .solid,
            textColor: .lightGray,
            size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)))
        goToMessagesCell.accessoryView = imageView
    }
}
```

How do I offset my image view so that the image is aligned?

Comment: It should be aligned automatically. No need to mess with the image view's frame.

Comment: Manipulating the frame didn't affect anything for me, actually. The image also seems to be fine (no extra insets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my UIImage, other images don't have those extra insets.